# What causes byteOffset to be non-zero with Node fs.readFileSync?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, typed-arrays, uint8array

We have some data we're reading with code like:

```js
const readData = fs.readFileSync('./dummy')
```

And `readData` then looks like below, with a `byteOffset` of `4664`

[image]

We then need to make a buffer from that existing buffer by doing `Buffer.from(readData)` to get a result with a `byteOffset` of `0` for the data to be used in various applications, whether that's showing an image or decompressing some stored data from the file.

[image]

**The question:** I don't understand where this `byteOffset` comes from in this scenario, what its purpose is, and why we need to re-buffer the buffer data to get a usable output from `fs.readFileSync`.

I've read through the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufbyteoffset) but it hasn't helped to answer any of my questions.